# Reading for starter in Computer System Security

Tags: professional-education

What book is a best introduction to a computer systems security for a beginner in the field. One which covers the breadth as well as depth of security and finding vulnerabilities.

Comment: Hi cobie! This really isn't a good question for the site as it encourages list-type questions. Feel free to hop over to The DMZ, our chat room, to discuss about it though! I have got plenty of good book recommendations from there!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of great books that are generic "IT Security for dummies" - but actually, I would recommend that you read up a little on the type of threats first.  certainly, whilst it's a bit out of date now - I read "The Cuckoo's egg" by Cliff Stoll and it was really influential in shaping my career because before  security was cool - I was already taking steps to mould my career in that direction.

More recently I've read similar - but more up to date books - like

- "DarkerMarket: The Hunt for Lord Cyric"
- Kingpin: How One Hacker Took Over the Billion-Dollar Cybercrime
  Underground
- DarkMarket: CyberThieves, CyberCops and You
- Fatal System Error: The Hunt for the New Crime Lords Who are Bringing
  Down the Internet

These books don't weigh too heavily on technical terminology but will introduce the "business" side to IT Security and then you can start to specialise in whichever aspect of IT security fits best for you, e.g. application security, networking & security,  information risk, data protection etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you follow these three steps:

- First: Google how many areas has the computer security.
- Second: pick the one that attract you more.
- Third: edit the question and ask about a book for that specific area.

Another option would be Google certifications, pick one which subject-matter interest you, go to Amazon and buy a book (check the customers' opinions) related to that certification.

Answer (score 0):

Wiliiam Stallings' Network Security: Applications and Standards, 4/e is a good book to start with. It gives you general understanding of the concept and let's you to decide which area you want to dive in.